# ok to use led ceiling fan bulb in table lamp?

Tags: lamp, table

Just want to be sure it is safe to use a 25w LED bulb marked as ceiling fan in a regular table lamp.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the bulb in a normal table lamp so long as ...

- **Fitting**:The fitting is the same (E.g. standard Edison screw in US)
- **Voltage**: The bulb is marked the same voltage as your household standard voltage (120 V in US). The voltage is approximate, sometimes you will see 110 V - that's a small enough difference that it doesn't matter for our purposes.
- **Wattage**: The bulb wattage (25W) does not exceed the rating marked on the lamp-holder (unlikely to be a problem for any lamp-holder designed for traditional  standard plain ordinary old inefficient incandescent tungsten filament light bulbs like your grandfather used.) Lamp-holders are often marked something like "Max 40W".
- **Cooling**: There is room for air to flow around the bulb. LED bulbs can overheat in some types of small fully enclosed light fittings. This is unlikely to be a problem in any normal type of table lamp where the shade is open at top and bottom.

Nowadays  there are many different types of bulb. Some are designed for 12 V DC instead of 120 or 230 or 240 V AC. We can't see your ceiling fan so we can't be sure it isn't a weird one. That's why you should check markings on the bulb.

---

Footnotes:

Wattage is a guide to how much heat the bulb produces. It is no longer a useful guide to how much light the bulb produces. Sometimes the bulbs are marked with an "equivalent" wattage which you should be careful about understanding - it means *"this bulb is roughly as bright as an old-fashioned incandescent tungsten filament bulb that produced this amount of heat"*. Ignore that and look for the real Wattage. Wattage is really a measure of heat-producing power.

Lumens tells you how much light the bulb produces.

Comment: I would also add: Bulbs marked as "For ceiling fans" are explicitly built to withstand the vibrations from the fan, so they are fine when used elsewhere. There are similar indicators and/or markings for garage door opener (vibration), fridge (cold temp), oven (high temp) and "rough service" (vibration/bumps/shocks) bulbs. These can all be used as "normal" bulbs, they just generally cost a bit more so it usually doesn't make sense to buy specialty bulbs for a non-specialty purpose.